# SVN - block commits or checkins based on a condition

Tags: svn

Is there any way to block checkins if a condition is true ? Example, no checkins after 7PM. If it can be done, then I want to be able to move these checkins into the repo once the checkins are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook scripts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks) on the server side to do this sort of thing.  Specifically, you'd want to create a 'pre-commit' hook script that uses the current time to determine whether or not to allow a commit.  Your repository's hook script folder should be pre-populated with some script templates that you can use as a starting point.

Hook scripts will let you selectively allow or reject individual commits.  If I'm reading your question correctly, you also want those rejected commits to automatically get committed at some future point in time.  If that is indeed the case, then the last part can't be done with a hook script.  The hook script can only accept or reject the commit.  It's up to the committer to try the commit again at the appropriate time.  The server doesn't retain any information about the failed commit.  If this is what you're trying to do, please give more information about specifically what you're doing, including why commits shouldn't be allowed during this window.  There's probably a way to do what you want using a different approach.

Comment: Actually, I want to do the time check only on one day, every month. I should be able to manually turn the checkin-allowed on or off.

Comment: The absolute *simplest* thing to do would be to simply stop the Subversion server process and then start it back up again after the window of time has elapsed.  No Subversion hook scripts needed.  Depending on how you set everything up, this should be easy to do both automatically and manually.